# Diffraction of light

Tags: visible-light, waves, diffraction

[image]

If $l_1$ and $l_2$ are parallel how can they both can hit same spot? 
Why their difference in path length is $l_2 - l_1 = d \sin \theta$ instead of 0?

Comment: The clue is in the term "compressed scale": $L \gg d$. The difference in path length is simply trigonometry.

Answer (score 6):

The two beams $l_1$ and $l_2$ are **not** parallel. The angles they make with the horizontal is:

$$\theta_{l_1} = \arctan\left(\frac{s-d/2}{L}\right) $$

$$\theta_{l_2} = \arctan\left(\frac{s+d/2}{L}\right) $$

However the difference between these two angles is so small compared with $\theta$ that it is an excellent approximation to assume they are parallel. If the angles are all small then we can use the approximation $\arctan\theta \approx \theta$ to get:

$$\frac{\theta_{l_2} - \theta_{l_1}}{\theta} \approx \frac{d}{s} $$

and in most circumstances $d \ll s$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the hint is in the words "compressed scale" i.e $L>>d$ . So the lines
intersect at a point. They subtend certain angles with the horizontal.

When $L$ and $d$ are comparable, the picture is like below:
[image]

As for your second question, $$l_2 - l_1 = d \tan \theta \,\ (\text{from diagram})$$
$$ =d \sin \theta \,\ (\text{since $\theta$ is very small, we approximate $\sin \theta = \tan \theta$})$$